# SQL Adding a column to a table, with case statement

Tags: sql

*I have my case statement but would like to add the new column "Unit_Type" to the table...*

```
Unit_type =(case [INSP_UNIT_TYPE_ID] 
    when '9' then 'Semi Trailer'
    when '7' then 'Pole Trailer'
    when '6' then 'Other'
    when '5' then 'Motor Carrier'
    when '3' then 'Full Trailer'
    when '2' then 'Dolly Converter'
    when '14' then 'Intermodal Chassis'
    when '12' then 'Van'
    when '11' then 'Truck Tractor'
    when '10' then 'Straight Truck'
    else 'Invalid'
        end)    from [dbo].[Insp_Unit_Pub_01012015_05282015];
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add this case to the table with the rest of the fields and would create a new table

Comment: You want to create a new table from exisiting table?

Comment: You want to create new table, or Just Creating Select Query?

Comment: First `ALTER TABLE` to add the column (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)  then `UPDATE TABLE SET Unit_Type = (case statement)` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388064/sql-update-rows-in-column-using-case-statement)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If you are trying to create a new table, is there any reason why you can't `SELECT *,Unit_type = (case statement) INTO [New_Table] FROM [dbo].[Insp_Unit_Pub_01012015_05282015]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't do that and use a view.

the above suggestion is the result of a wild guess because you provide neither context nor database structure so it may be plain wrong or not suitable for your situation.

your untold requirement looks like some kind of visualization of the table with human readable data and that's what views are good for.

create a view adding the required joins or including the CASE statement you are trying to put in the table (check the syntax ^^):

```
CREATE VIEW [name of the view here]
AS
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3,
       Unit_type = CASE [INSP_UNIT_TYPE_ID] 
        WHEN '9' THEN 'Semi Trailer'
        WHEN '7' THEN 'Pole Trailer'
        WHEN '6' THEN 'Other'
        WHEN '5' THEN 'Motor Carrier'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Full Trailer'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Dolly Converter'
        WHEN '14' THEN 'Intermodal Chassis'
        WHEN '12' THEN 'Van'
        WHEN '11' THEN 'Truck Tractor'
        WHEN '10' THEN 'Straight Truck'
        ELSE 'Invalid'
       END
FROM [dbo].[Insp_Unit_Pub_01012015_05282015];
```

as suggested by some comment you may put a `JOIN` in the query instead of the `CASE` statement if the human readable text comes from a lookup table.

Comment: Thanks I will keep this in mind when using a view will suffice. In this particular case I want that field and/or edit the field it is based upon. End result will be to use the updated table to upload in another tool.

Answer (score 14):

You seem to be using SQL Server.  Just add a computed column:

```
alter table Insp_Unit_Pub_01012015_05282015
    add Unit_Type as (case [INSP_UNIT_TYPE_ID] 
                        when '9' then 'Semi Trailer'
                        when '7' then 'Pole Trailer'
                        when '6' then 'Other'
                        when '5' then 'Motor Carrier'
                        when '3' then 'Full Trailer'
                        when '2' then 'Dolly Converter'
                        when '14' then 'Intermodal Chassis'
                        when '12' then 'Van'
                        when '11' then 'Truck Tractor'
                        when '10' then 'Straight Truck'
                        else 'Invalid'
                     end);
```

This does the calculation when you fetch the value.  The advantage is that you don't have to write a trigger to change the value when `INSP_UNIT_TYPE_ID` changes.

By the way, this question suggests that you need a reference table for `INSP_UNIT_TYPE`, with `INSP_UNIT_TYPE_ID` as the primary key.  A `JOIN` is actually a better way to get the value (although using a computed column with a `JOIN` is rather cumbersome).

Comment: The refernce table approach would be best as all it requires is a new entry if a new type is added and no code change is needed.